# Make a coroutine faster when using WaitForSeconds()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was looking for a way to make a coroutine work faster based on `WaitForSeconds()` function. The minimal I have gone to is 0.001f. But I cannot go even further. The higher the coroutine timer => more time to wait, the lesser the coroutine timer => the lesser time to wait. I am using Coroutine to fade in/out a sphere and was trying to make the fading work a lot faster.

```
IEnumerator FadeOut()
{
    fadeValueOut = 1f;

    while (fadeValueOut >= -1f)
    {
        color = FadeSphere.material.color;
        color.a = fadeValueOut;
        FadeSphere.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_Color", color);
        fadeValueOut -= 0.1f;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.001f); //Make the coroutine faster?
    }      
}
```

Comment: try ```new WaitForEndOfFrame()``` or ```new WaitForFixedUpdate()```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to Update the colors alpha more often than the frame rate can possibly be.

*(1000 times a second vs a normal 60 top end 120)*

But to accelerate the fade you can literally just increase the amount the alpha changes each frame and to achieve an each frame wait use `null` for the return type.

Also you are changing the alpha by a set amount not an amount that adjusts to the framerate so it won't be a smooth transition.

This is a simple fadeout method that accelerates how fast it fades.

```
private IEnumerator FadeOut()
{
    Renderer rend = FadeSphere.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    Color color = rend.material.color;

    float speed = 5f;
    float acceleration = 10f;

    float alpha = 1f;

    while (alpha > 0)
    {
        speed += Time.deltaTime * acceleration;
        alpha -= Time.deltaTime * speed;
        if (alpha < 0)
        {
            alpha = 0f;
        }
        rend.material.color = new Color(color.r, color.g, color.b, alpha);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```